# numbered list inside alphabetical list

Tags: lists, enumerate

I'm using `\begin{enumerate}[label={\alph*)}]` to create alphabetical lists in LaTeX. However, any nested `enumerate`-environment will inherent that property. How can I use the standard numbered lists inside alphabetical lists? How to change `label` back to the default value?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Use `\arabic` instead.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that fixed it :) If you'd post that as an answer, I could mark it as answered.

Comment: I've posted it, you can tick the arrow ;)

Comment: Had to wait several minutes :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `\arabic` instead of `\alph`.